# bug when use getline insead of cin for struct

Tags: c++, struct

My code is doing fine, but when I change `cin>>new_person.address` into `getline`, I am having bugs when I run it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    string name;
    string address;
    int phone_number;
};

person getNewPerson()
{
    person new_person;
    cout<<"Enter a name ";
    cin>>new_person.name;
    cout<<"Enter an address ";
    getline(cin, new_person.address, '\n');
    cout<<"Enter a phone number ";
    cin>>new_person.phone_number;
    return new_person;
}
person printPerson(person a_person)
{
    cout<<"This person name is: "<<a_person.name<<endl;
    cout<<"His address is: "<<a_person.address<<endl;
    cout<<"His phone number is: "<<a_person.phone_number<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    person my_person=getNewPerson();
    printPerson(my_person);
}
```

When I use `getline(cin, new_person.address, '\n');` it skips that statement for no reason and goes to the next one. Dunno what is going on, copy and paste the code please and you will understand.

Comment: The problem is that I used cin for the first string and getline for the second string. After making the both strings getline the program works perfectly.

Comment: the problem was that I should have used cin.ignore();

Answer (score 0):

It is designed like that. In C++ `std::cin >> str;` reads the next word in stream. More specifically, it reads the next token and tokens are separated by whitespace so effectively they represents one word.

Use `getline` function to input more than one word.

Comment: Try the code and you will understand what I mean! When I use getline for struct it skip that statement and goes to the next(cin>> for integer).

Comment: needed to use cin.ignore() to prevent the skipping of getline